# How can I create Texture Map from Geometry Node Instances/Mesh on surface?

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry-nodes

I'm creating a product image of a can with condensation. The condensation is made through geometry nodes.

To make the label feel realistic, I would like to use the location of the droplets to create a mask (image texture) that I can plug into the roughness of my label texture.

How can I take this information of the created droplet instances/meshes and set it up on the UV Map of the can? I feel like this information should be available.

Is this even possible?

[image: Can with UV Map][image: Rendered Can and Label]